# jQuery Div Toggle Switcher

Tags: jquery, radio-button, toggle

I am using this jQuery code that uses radio buttons to toggle two different divs

```
$(function() {
$("[name=toggler]").click(function(){
        $('.toHide').hide();
        $("#blk-"+$(this).val()).show('slow');
});
```

});

Here is the HTML

```
<label><input id="rdb1" type="checkbox" name="toggler" value="1" />First</label>
    <label><input id="rdb2" type="checkbox" name="toggler" value="2" />Second</label>
    
    <div id="blk-1" class="toHide" style="display:none">
        First div content
    </div>
    <div id="blk-2" class="toHide" style="display:none">
        Second div content
    </div>
```

This works awesome, but I'm trying to style this like an IOS toggle switch, but I keep getting two toggle switches for each input, it still functions but just trying to make one button that turns on and off.

Comment: *I'm trying to style this like an IOS toggle switch* - that's the relevant bit of code that you'll need to include.

Comment: here is the JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eKFrW/

Comment: Still no "IOS toggle switch" in that fiddle (which is just a duplicate of what's here) - please update the question to include what you've tried when you say you "keep getting two"

Comment: Sorry, I want it to look like this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_switch
but I keep getting two of those toggle switches per radio button

Comment: Sorry, without your code, we can't see *why* you're getting two.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2d43nt9b/1/ Here it is

Comment: Right, it's because in your fiddle you have **two** *radio buttons*, so you get... **two** toggle buttons - review your w3schools link which has one toggle for one checkbox.  Please update the question code here, which also shows two checkboxes.

Comment: But I need to be able to show/hide two divs, which works in my first JS Fiddle example.

Comment: So what's the actual question?  You've asked: *why am I getting two buttons when I have two buttons*

Comment: The actual question is i need to be able to hide/show two different divs. My first example (the js fiddle) works great. It shows and hides my two divs, but I would like it to be a toggle button (like the w3 schools example) I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this, I just keep breaking the code or I get two toggle buttons which I don't want. I want to toggle on and off between the two divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to be able to hide/show two different divs
>
> make one button that turns on and off

You'll want a *single* checkbox so that you get a *single* "IOS" toggle button.  This will require some minor changes to your js:

```
var toShow = $(this).is(":checked") ? "blk-2" : "blk-1";
$("#" + toShow).show('slow');
```

With no changes to your css (from the fiddle link), giving:

```js
$("[name=toggler]").click(function() {
  $('.toHide').hide();
  var toShow = $(this).is(":checked") ? "blk-2" : "blk-1";
  $("#" + toShow).show('slow');
});
```

```css
/* The switch - the box around the slider */

.toggler {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}


/* Hide default HTML checkbox */

.toggler input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}


/* The slider */

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="toggler"><input id="rdb1" type="checkbox" name="toggler"/><span class="slider round"></span></label>

<div id="blk-1" class="toHide">
  money
</div>
<div id="blk-2" class="toHide" style="display:none">
  interest
</div>
```

Comment: This works great on here, but only works once on my page, and doesn't show my other div that I'm trying to display when I toggle back and forth

Comment: Make sure you have the correct IDs.  Make sure you edit the question with your code.

Comment: I got it to work, THANK YOU!!!!! You are my lord and savior.